# Box that displays random divs

Tags: javascript, html, random

I am trying to create a kind of box which suppose to display random divs. For example with fun facts about animals. I found some code, wrote some on my own and it works this way:
 1. random div is loaded when page is loading
 2. next random divs are loaded everytime user click the button: "Random fun facts"

In the code below the button "Rundom fun facts" works only once. How can I make it to work continousely? I mean the way that I can click on it 100 times and it will display 100 various divs. And here is my second question: When using for example 100 divs (there are many fun facts about animals) the code below would be very long, is there a simpler way with some kind of creating a loop?
There are tons of sliders but I couldn't find anything like I need. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="box">
  <div id="funfact1">
      <p>
      Squirrels plant thousands of new trees each year simply by           forgetting where they put their acorns. </p>
    </div><!-- end funfact1 -->

    <div id="funfact2">
      <p>Macaques in Japan use coins to buy vending machine snacks.       </p>
    </div><!-- end funfact2 -->

    <div id="funfact3">
      <p>Japanese Macaques make snowballs for fun. </p>
    </div><!-- end funfact3 -->

    <div id="funfact4">
      <p>Dogs’ nose prints are as unique as human fingerprints and       can be used to identify them. </p>
    </div><!--end funfact4 -->
    <div id="buttonDiv">
      <button id="buttonShuffle">Random fun fact</button>
     </div><!-- end buttonDiv -->
</div><!-- end div box -->
<script type="text/javascript">
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);

window.onload = function() {
    if (randomNumber == 1) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (randomNumber == 2) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (randomNumber == 3) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (randomNumber == 4) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "inline";
    }
}

randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);
    document.getElementById("buttonShuffle").onclick=function() {
    if (randomNumber1 == 1) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (randomNumber1 == 2) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (randomNumber1 == 3) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (randomNumber1 == 4) {
        document.getElementById("funfact1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("funfact4").style.display = "inline";
    }
}

</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbouf1o2/6/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all your div and write a less repetitive code, you can try this. In general, when you write code, try to identify repetitions and export their in functions.

```
window.onload = function() {

  // show random fact on load
  randomFact()

  // show random fact on button click
  document.getElementById("buttonShuffle").addEventListener('click', randomFact)
}

function randomFact () {
  // generate random
  var random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)

  // get all facts
  var funfacts = document.getElementsByClassName('funfact')

  // hide all facts
  for (var i = 0; i < funfacts.length; i++) {
    funfacts[i].style.display = 'none'
  }

  // show one
  funfacts[random].style.display = 'inline'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxv7y6x9/

Comment: This is the best answer! Voting over mine. :)

Comment: Thanks =) you can also export random number generation in a function which return a different one from the previous.

Comment: Quentin - this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. Btw, how to modify the function which return a different number from the provious one? I wouldn't have asked if you haven't mentioned about this :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kxv7y6x9/2/. It's generic, you can add number of fact you want, if they have the `funfact` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div id="box">
  <p id="funFacts"></p>
</div><!-- end div box -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var funFacts = [
              'Squirrels plant thousands of new trees each year simply by           forgetting where they put their acorns. ',
              'Macaques in Japan use coins to buy vending machine snacks.      ' ,
              'Japanese Macaques make snowballs for fun. ' ];
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (funFacts.length-1));

  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = funFacts[randomNumber];
  };
  document.getElementById("buttonShuffle").onclick=function() {
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (funFacts.length-1));
  document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = funFacts[randomNumber1];
}

</script>
```

What problem you are facing is that you are generating randomNumber1 outside the function which is running only once and not on each call of buttonShuffle.
Next problem you had was to not write some many divs which you can see that I have solved using an array of funfacts.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I tried it earlier with using an array but couldn't make it right. Now I see how it should have been done.

Comment: @YoungBuck Yes. You can accept the answer if found it fixing your problem. It may help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This will fix your problem,**

And if you want to dynamic the posts count you can do something like this,

HTML,

```
<div id="box">

    <div class="text">
      <p>Squirrels plant thousands of new trees each year simply by forgetting where they put their acorns</p>
    </div><!-- end funfact1 -->

    <div class="text">
      <p>Macaques in Japan use coins to buy vending machine snacks.</p>
    </div><!-- end funfact2 -->

    <div class="text">
      <p>Japanese Macaques make snowballs for fun.</p>
    </div><!-- end funfact3 -->

    <div class="text">
      <p>Dogs’ nose prints are as unique as human fingerprints and can be used to identify them. </p>
    </div><!--end funfact4 -->

    <div id="buttonDiv">
      <button id="buttonShuffle">Random fun fact</button>
    </div><!-- end buttonDiv -->

</div><!-- end div box -->
```

Javascript,

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('text'),
    randomNumber;

function updateNumber(){
   randomNumber = (Math.floor((Math.random() * texts.length) + 1)) - 1;
}

function updateText(){
    updateNumber();
    for (i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      texts[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    texts[randomNumber].style.display = "block";
}

window.onload = function(){
    updateText();
}

document.getElementById('buttonShuffle').onclick = function(){
    updateText();
}
```

CSS,

```
#box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border: solid thin blue;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#buttonDiv {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 120px;

}
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/xbouf1o2/21/

Answer (score 0):

> In the code below the button "Random fun facts" works only once. How can I make >it to work continuously?

The reason this happens is because your `randomNumber1` variable is calculated once. You need to calculate your random number within the onclick event. This way, every time you click the button, a random number is generated, and the associated fun fact is displayed.

> When using for example 100 divs (there are many fun facts about animals) the >code below would be very long, is there a simpler way with some kind of >creating a loop?

First, you need to remove the ID from each fun fact, and add a class instead. Now you can use JS to grab all fun facts using `document.getElementsByClassName(class)`. This will return a nodelist that we can loop through.

Second, create a function which will do the shuffling for you.

```
function shuffleRandomFunfact(event) {
  // Generate a random number.
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  // Loop through the nodelist.
  for (var i = 0; i < funfacts.length; i++) {
    // If the index of the current funfact is the same
    // as the random number.
    if (i === randomNumber)
      funfacts[i].style.display = 'inline';
    // Otherwise ...
    funfacts[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Now, you just need to attach the above function to your event listeners.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbouf1o2/22/)